# what git log shows me didn't match what git rebase -i head~3 shows me

Tags: git, github, rebase

I’m having problems with rebase. I want to squash some builds, but I can´t.

This is what I get when I execute the command `git log –oneline`:

```
git log --oneline
2e6d3cf Fix bug fetching data
4abe96e conflicts merged
34d130d latam_schedule with geotargeted languaje and data fetching
8687f73 removes extra lines, and add the includes I remove before.
eed4f10 unnecessary adds and sample block removed
d2d58e6 latam_schedule with geotargeted languaje and data fetching
75b1b6d parseo el string para extraer las horas.
8a3b067 Agrego un render con datos reales
d856ef1 Agrego un render de data dummy
7331f83 Alert removed(commented)
128bfc1 First LATAM commit
4dd79cb Merge pull request #1016 from matterhorn/disco-608-bugfix
```

The problem is that I don’t see the 2e6d3cf, 4abe96e and 34d130d commits that I want to squash when I execute `git rebase HEAD~3`.

Instead of the three commits I have, I see the following when I execute `git rebase -i HEAD~3`:

```
pick 34d130d latam_schedule with geotargeted languaje and data fetching
pick d2d58e6 latam_schedule with geotargeted languaje and data fetching
pick eed4f10 unnecessary adds and sample block removed
pick 8687f73 removes extra lines, and add the includes I remove before.
pick 2e6d3cf Fix bug fetching data
```

The thing is that I don’t know why d2d58e6, eed4f10 and 8687f73 are in the list. In the other hand, If I try to go ahead and squash, there are a lot of conflicts that shouldn’t be there (like trying to merge files that are too old).

This is what `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` shows

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate
* 2e6d3cf (HEAD, matterhorn-latam/latam, latam) Fix bug fetching data
*   4abe96e conflicts merged
|\
| * 8687f73 (matterhorn-latam/master, master) removes extra lines, and add the includes I remove before.
| * eed4f10 unnecessary adds and sample block removed
| * d2d58e6 latam_schedule with geotargeted languaje and data fetching
* | 34d130d latam_schedule with geotargeted languaje and data fetching
|/
* 75b1b6d parseo el string para extraer las horas.
* 8a3b067 Agrego un render con datos reales
* d856ef1 Agrego un render de data dummy
* 7331f83 Alert removed(commented)
* 128bfc1 First LATAM commit
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`. Also, keep in mind that rebase doesn't preserve merge commits unless you use `-p` or `--preserve-merges`. Also, your question is a little confusing, because some of the commits that you say are missing from the rebase editor are in fact there, just in reverse order, because rebase applies commits in the reverse order that they show up in `git log`.

Comment: I just added that information to the post.

Comment: Right. You're getting unexpected results because you're not using `--preserve-merges`. However, what do you mean by "`2e6d3cf`, `4abe96e` and `34d130d` commits that I want to merge when I execute `git rebase HEAD~3`"? Why do you mean by "merge"? Did you mean that you want to ***squash*** these commits? "Merge" has a very specific meaning in git: to merge two branches together. That's not what you want to do with these commits, is it? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I just edited the post. You are right, I want to "squash" my tree last comits. Several things confuses me, like: Why if I'm using "HEAD~3", I'm not getting just the last 3 commits? Thanks

Comment: Note: be careful if your `git log` is during a reword of an interactive rebase: see "[`git rebase -i` shows wrong commit history after a rebase and force push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362522/6309)".  
Use Git 2.24+ (Q4 2019).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The necessary commits are not observed because `HEAD~3` tells git to always follow the first parent in the commit tree, which happens to follow the merged branch history<sup>‡</sup>, which is, from your question, not the history you are after.

You need to explicitly select between `commit^1` and `commit^2` (and also `commit^3` for octopus merges) to navigate the tree. For your example:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate
* 2e6d3cf HEAD
*   4abe96e HEAD^1 = HEAD~1 (! History branches here. !)
|\
| * 8687f73 HEAD^1^1 = HEAD^^ = HEAD~2
| * eed4f10 HEAD^^^ = HEAD~3
| * d2d58e6 HEAD^^^^ = HEAD~4
* | 34d130d HEAD^2   (! Note !)
|/
* 75b1b6d HEAD^2^ = HEAD^^^^^ = HEAD~5
* 8a3b067 ...
* d856ef1 ...
* 7331f83 ...
```

---

<sup>‡</sup> The order is a bit unusual here as a merge commit records the parents such that the HEAD at the time of the merge is always the *first* parent, and that implies that you must have been on the 8687f73 when you've done the merge for it to count as the first.

Comment: Can you add the git command for starting the rebase?

Comment: @mockinterface I know this is kinda old but can you share how the command should be?